# User account code with GET and POST

Tags: python, beginner, google-app-engine

I'm new to Python and GAE, but years of procedural programming. I have this code, but I know that there must be some better solution to avoid retyping code.

The first and last section of code are identical in both GET and POST methods, so I suppose there must be another way to share the identical code.

```
# This class manage the user account
class MyAccount(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
                """ Shows actual user account """

                # Get actual user
                user = users.get_current_user()

                if user:
                        # Get the actual user data
                        data = Person.gql("WHERE username = :nick",
                                                            nick=user.nickname()).get()

                        # Test if we found the user
                        if data:
                                templateValues['data'] = data
                                template = jinja_environment.get_template('myAccount.htm')
                        else:
                                templateValues['custom_msg'] = "The logged user is not available."
                                template = jinja_environment.get_template('customMessage.htm')

                else:
                        templateValues['custom_msg'] = "You are not logged in. Please, login to access to your account"
                        template = jinja_environment.get_template('customMessage.htm')

                # Render the page
                self.response.out.write(template.render(templateValues))

        def post(self):
                """ Saves user updated data """

                # Get actual user
                user = users.get_current_user()

                if user:
                        # Get the actual user data
                        person = Person.gql("WHERE username = :nick",
                                                            nick=user.nickname()).get()

                        # Test if we found the user
                        if person:
                                person.username = self.request.get('username')
                                person.password = self.request.get('password')
                                if person.email: self.request.get('email')
                                person.name = self.request.get('name')
                                person.lastname = self.request.get('lastname')
                                person.idnumber = self.request.get('idnumber')

                                templateValues['data'] = person
                                template = jinja_environment.get_template('myAccount.htm')

                        else:
                                templateValues['custom_msg'] = "The logged user is not available."
                                template = jinja_environment.get_template('customMessage.htm')

                else:
                        templateValues['custom_msg'] = "You are not logged in. Please, login to access to your account."
                        template = jinja_environment.get_template('customMessage.htm')

                # Render the page
                self.response.out.write(template.render(templateValues))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line looks suspicious:

```
            if person.email: self.request.get('email')
```

I assume it should be:

```
            person.email = self.request.get('email')
```

Your code seem to be using excessive indentation. The python standard is four space per level.

You are using `templateValues` but don't seem to define it anywhere.

To refactor this, I'd start by removing the section of that that's different between the two methods into their own function:

```
# This class manage the user account
class MyAccount(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def show_user(self, user):
        # Get the actual user data
        data = Person.gql("WHERE username = :nick",
                                            nick=user.nickname()).get()
        # Test if we found the user
        if data:
            templateValues['data'] = data
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('myAccount.htm')
        else:
            templateValues['custom_msg'] = "The logged user is not available."
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('customMessage.htm')

        return template, templateValues



    def get(self):
        """ Shows actual user account """

        # Get actual user
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            template, templateValues = self.show_user(user)
        else:
            templateValues['custom_msg'] = "You are not logged in. Please, login to access to your account"
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('customMessage.htm')

        # Render the page
        self.response.out.write(template.render(templateValues))

    def update_user(self, user):
        # Get the actual user data
        person = Person.gql("WHERE username = :nick",
                nick=user.nickname()).get()
        # Test if we found the user
        if person:
            person.username = self.request.get('username')
            person.password = self.request.get('password')
            person.email = self.request.get('email')
            person.name = self.request.get('name')
            person.lastname = self.request.get('lastname')
            person.idnumber = self.request.get('idnumber')

            templateValues['data'] = person
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('myAccount.htm')
        else:
            templateValues['custom_msg'] = "The logged user is not available."
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('customMessage.htm')

        return template, templateValues


    def post(self):
        """ Saves user updated data """
        # Get actual user
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            template, templateValues = self.update_user(user)
        else:
            templateValues['custom_msg'] = "You are not logged in. Please, login to access to your account."
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('customMessage.htm')
        # Render the page
        self.response.out.write(template.render(templateValues))
```

The only thing different between `post` and `get` is the function they call. We'll just pass the function as a parameter to a new function.

```
    def request(self, handler):
        """ Shows actual user account """

        # Get actual user
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            template, templateValues = handler(user)
        else:
            templateValues['custom_msg'] = "You are not logged in. Please, login to access to your account"
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('customMessage.htm')

        # Render the page
        self.response.out.write(template.render(templateValues))

    def get(self):
        return self.request(self.show_user)

    def post(self):
        return self.request(self.update_user)
```

The current code repeats calls to `get_template` a lot. So we'll refactor it so that it only happens once. We'll just store the name of the template in a variable and load it just before we render it.

```
def show_user(self, user):
    # Get the actual user data
    data = Person.gql("WHERE username = :nick",
                                        nick=user.nickname()).get()
    # Test if we found the user
    if data:
        templateValues['data'] = data
        template = 'myAccount.htm'
    else:
        templateValues['custom_msg'] = "The logged user is not available."
        template = 'customMessage.htm'

    return template, templateValues



def request(self, handler):
    """ Shows actual user account """

    # Get actual user
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
        template, templateValues = handler(user)
    else:
        templateValues['custom_msg'] = "You are not logged in. Please, login to access to your account"
        template = 'customMessage.htm'

    # Render the page
    template = jinja_environment.get_template(template)
    self.response.out.write(template.render(templateValues))
```

But we can clean up our actual work functions a little more:

```
def show_user(self, user):
    # Get the actual user data
    data = Person.gql("WHERE username = :nick",
                                        nick=user.nickname()).get()
    # Test if we found the user
    if data:
        return 'myAccount.htm', {
                'data' : data
        }
    else:
        return 'custom_msg.htm', {
                'custom_msg' : "The logged user is not available."
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I love python everyday more and more. It's flexibility has no limits!!
Great trick the function as parameter to a function

Comment: By the way, I pasted the code in my text editor, which made this strange indentation (double tab, instead tab), but is 4 spaces normally. And you are right in the other 2 supositions.

Answer (score 0):

A little more clean up (sorry, I can't code on the answer link):

Get inside request the common part for show_user and update_user (which only differs on the name of the var, data or person). This is the final code. Thank you very much.

```
# This class manage the user account
class MyAccount(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def show_user(self, person):
        templateValues = {}
        templateValues['data'] = person
        template = 'myAccount.htm'

        return template, templateValues

    def update_user(self, person):
        person.username = self.request.get('username')
        person.password = self.request.get('password')
        person.email = self.request.get('email')
        person.name = self.request.get('name')
        person.lastname = self.request.get('lastname')
        person.idnumber = self.request.get('idnumber')

        templateValues = {}
        templateValues['data'] = person
        template = 'myAccount.htm'

        return template, templateValues

    def requested(self, handler):
        """ Shows actual user account """

        # Get actual user
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            # Get the actual user data
            person = Person.gql("WHERE username = :nick",
                            nick=user.nickname()).get()
            # Test if we found the user
            if person:
                template, templateValues = handler(person)
            else:
                templateValues['custom_msg'] = "The logged user is not available."
                template = 'customMessage.htm'
        else:
            templateValues['custom_msg'] = "You are not logged in. Please, login to access to your account"
            template = 'customMessage.htm'

        # Render the page
        template = jinja_environment.get_template(template)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(templateValues))

    def get(self):
        return self.requested(self.show_user)

    def post(self):
        return self.requested(self.update_user)
```